# 2 outputs of same op amp gives different voltages

Tags: operational-amplifier, thermocouple

[image]I am using lm358p op-amp for 2 different heaters I connected both of them in a single op-amp and it didn't work firstly I thought that the problem was thermocouples I swapped them but the problem kept going then I made the connections in a breadboard when I used the first amplifier it worked just fine and then I swapped the amplifiers and 2nd amplifier gave a different value (note: I didn't change anything else and I tried with a 2.0v power supply too) I changed the resistors the capacitors checked all of them but it still doesn't works could you help me here is my schematic

Comment: There are parameters like offset, drift, ..etc. The LM358 might not be suitable at all for a thermocouple, also you could post draw a schematics with a tool that is used in this forum. Draw the input, inverting non-inverting, resistors and output to MCU - without anything else.

Comment: Your schematic is more like a "hookup", showing how everything is connected instead of focusing on the functionality of the circuit. For the Arduino part that's OK but it makes the opamp circuit indistinguishable. I suggest that you make your circuits to look like figure 5 in this article: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/cmos-op-amp-outperforms-bipolar-amps-in-precision-applications.html I agree with Marko that the LM358 probably isn't a good choice as it is a very "bare bones" opamp.

Comment: LM358 and thermocouples is a bad idea.

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=690776.0;attach=368880 here is more clear schematic